# Best way for main/calling thread to wait for other threads to complete their tasks: Thread.sleep(), Latch, CompletableFuture, or something else?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads

What's the best way for the main/calling thread to wait for other threads to complete their tasks? I came up with two options; there are probably more.

**Option 1 - Thread.sleep()**

```
new Thread(() -> System.out.println("Executed task 1")).start();
new Thread(() -> System.out.println("Executed task 2")).start();
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

**Option 2 - Latch**

```
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(2);

new Thread(() -> {
        System.out.println("Executed task 1");
        latch.countDown();
    }).start();

new Thread(() -> {
         System.out.println("Executed task 2");
         latch.countDown();
     }).start();

latch.await(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

**Option 3 - CompletableFuture**

```
CompletableFuture<Void> future1 = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> System.out.println("Executed task 1"));
CompletableFuture<Void> future2 = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> System.out.println("Executed task 2"));
CompletableFuture.allOf(future1, future2).join();
```

**Option 4 - ??**

Comment: `Thread.sleep()` is never useful for thread synchronization.  If you find yourself using it for that purpose, you're doing something wrong.  Full stop.

Comment: Don't use Threads in an explicit way like shown. Since the arrival of the Concurrency Framework in Java 5, to use this is to be favoured over using threads manually.

Comment: @AndrewHenle is right, don't use sleep(). You can .join() both of threads instead.If you have to wait for some threads to be completed/finished(run() is out), .join() is what was designed for. btw, it also makes HB edge. CountDownLatch is good for step by step scenarios. Your example is also OK, but in more complex business logic, executing in the thread, just make sure latch.countDown() is called in any case (using finally section, for example). As for CompletableFuture, I'd use them for a number of very short living jobs. For one specific  long living job I prefer explicit Thread to be used.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`Thread.join()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html):

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(...);
Thread t2 = new Thread(...);

t1.start();
t2.start();

t1.join();
t2.join();
```

---

The problem with using `Thread.sleep` is, hopefully obviously, there is no guarantee that the threads have completed; but also it can potentially be waiting for up to 1 second too long, if the threads complete immediately.

But there is a more important problem, which is that you don't get a memory consistency guarantee when you use it: there is no guarantee that work done in the threads is visible to the waiting thread after the sleep.

You do get memory consistency guarantees from using either `join()` or `await(...)`.